# Proof of theorem 2.1 and conclusion 2.2 in Sh:31 (Categoricity of Uncountable theories)

Tags: model-theory

Shelah in his paper stated the following two results (directly quoting from the paper):

> Theorem 2.1. For $\lambda > |T|$, $T$ has a model $M$ of cardinality $\lambda$, such that for all $m < \omega$, $A \subseteq |M|$, $|\{p\ |\ p \in S^m(A), p \text{ realized in } M\}| \leq |A| + |T|$.
>
> Proof. Take $M$ as an Ehrenfeucht-Mostowski model, which is the closure of a well-ordered set (See [Mo 1]).

And,

> Conclusion 2.2. If $T$ is categorical in $\lambda$, $|T| \leq \mu < \lambda$, then $T$ is stable in $\mu$.

Both of these references Morley's *Categoricity in Power* paper, which I have tried to go over, but did not get very far.

My question is essentially, for theorem 2.1, $M = EM(I)$ for some well-ordered set $I$, how is this $I$ defined?

For conclusion 2.2, this follows directly from theorem 2.1 and Upwards Lowenheim-Skolem, correct?

Comment: The point of Sh:31 is to generalize Morley's Categoricity Theorem to uncountable languages. The proof in this case requires *significantly* more technical work. Just a piece of advice: If you haven't thoroughly internalized the proof of Morley's theorem, I highly recommend that you work through a textbook presentation of that proof (e.g. from Marker or Hodges or Tent-Ziegler or Chang-Keisler) before reading Shelah's paper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may find a proof of of Theorem 2.1 (with $T$ countable, but it does not really matter) in the book *Model Theory* by Chang and Keisler. In the 3rd edition (1990) it is Corollary 3.3.14

The key point is that the well-ordered set that generates $M$ has to be an indiscernible sequence. Also, the language needs to have Skolem functions (which we can add without increasing the cardinaity of the language).